# non-blocking i/o using select

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I have a sample client-server program that does non-blocking I/O for several sockets not using processes or threads. It uses `select`. Unfortunately, the server just shows lots of blank lines and that's all. Where is the mistake?
Running on MacOS.

Thanks in advance.

**Server:**

```
import socket
import select

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 10001))
sock.listen()

conn1, _ = sock.accept()
conn2, _ = sock.accept()

conn1.setblocking(0)
conn2.setblocking(0)

epoll = select.poll()
epoll.register(conn1.fileno(), select.POLLIN | select.POLLOUT)
epoll.register(conn2.fileno(), select.POLLIN | select.POLLOUT)

conn_map = {
    conn1.fileno(): conn1,
    conn2.fileno(): conn2,
}

while True:
    events = epoll.poll(1)
    for fileno, event in events:
        if event & select.POLLIN:
            data = conn_map[fileno].recv(1024)
            print(data.decode('utf8'))
        elif event & select.POLLOUT:
            conn_map[fileno].send('ping'.encode('utf8'))
```

**Client:**

```
import socket
from multiprocessing import Pool

def create_socket_and_send_data(number):
    with socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', 10001)) as sock:
        try:
            sock.sendall(f'client {number}\n'.encode('utf8'))
        except socket.error as ex:
            print('data sending error', ex)

    print(f'data for {number} has been sent')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=2) as pool:
        pool.map(create_socket_and_send_data, range(2))
```

Comment: Your client never reads the `ping` that is sent to it. Shouldn't it read from the socket before closing? Also, you might want to use `print(data.decode('utf8'), end='')` to avoid printing a newline when you get an empty read from `recv`.

Comment: @DanielPryden a tiny edit `print(data.decode('utf8'), end='')` was enough to make it work! Thank you so much.

Comment: Not related to the question: make this elif `elif event & select.POLLOUT` an `if` for better performance. A socket can be both ready to read and ready to write in the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, the server just shows lots of blank lines and that's all.

Actually this is not true.
The server prints at the beginning the lines it got from the clients. After they've send these lines the client close the connection which means that `select.POLLIN` gets triggered again on the socket and `recv` returns empty data.

This empty data is the sign that the peer has closed the connection. Once it got this sign the server should close the connection to the client and remove the `fileno` from the `select`. Instead your server prints the empty string with a newline and continues to expect new `POLLIN` events. These will come again and again and will always an empty buffer, thus leading to all the empty lines you see.

Comment: Yes, adding `end` argument to `print` clarified the situation: `print(data.decode('utf8'), end='')`. Thanks!

Comment: I've added the next lines (converted to single line because it's not allowed to post multiline code in the comments) that is executed if the data is empty:
`epoll.unregister(conn_map[fileno]); del conn_map[fileno]; if not conn_map: print('The End!'); return`
it's enough to make my example work as expected

Answer (score 2):

`select` is paradoxically easier to use for input than for output. For input, you receive an event each time new data arrives on a socket, so you always ask for all the sockets and have something to process for every new event.

For output, `select` will just say that a socket if ready to accept new data. Which is almost always true except if you have just filled a buffer. So you should only poll for an output socket when you have something to write there.

So you should register your sockets with `select.POLLIN` only. For the write part, you should either directly write to a socket without polling if you can hope that the peer should always be able to receive, or set up a queue with pending output per socket, `modify` the polling state of a socket with `select.POLLIN | select.POLLOUT` when there is something in its queue and modify it back with `select.POLLIN` back when the queue is empty again.